# Can we do the domain migration for 4 node SQL cluster?

Tags: sql-server

Can we do the domain migration for 4 node SQL cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not supports migrating cluster from one domain to other. Their is support article describing this.

[This support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269196)  clearly mentiones that

> Because of an increased dependence on Active Directory Domain Services, Microsoft does not support moving an already installed and configured Windows `Server 2008`, `Windows Server 2008 R2` and `Windows Server 2012 failover` cluster from one domain to another. You must create a new cluster. Additionally, you must re-cluster highly available applications.

It would be better to rebuild the cluster from scratch in other domain.

In windows server 2016 you can have [cluster nodes in 2 different domain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2015/08/17/workgroup-and-multi-domain-clusters-in-windows-server-2016/)